# Find a shorter code for this function with If...else

Tags: javascript

What function do you suggest when you have a lot of parameters and only one condition to pass through? I want something like this.

```
function deleteClaimLine(secId, aBtn, cboF, lstServ, cboServ, cboServP, txtMont, txtAnn1, txtAnn2, txtAnn3, fileUpl, dBtn) {

            All variables...

            if (allParameters !== "") {
                allParameters.value = "";
            }
}
```

Actually, that's all conditions i have and i want to do it in only one line if possible:

```
            if (cboFamille !== "") {
                cboFamille.value = "";
            }
            if (lstServices !== "") {
                lstServices.value = "";
            }
            if (cboService !== "") {
                cboService.value = "";
                cboService.style.display = "none";
            }
            if (cboServiceP !== "") {
                cboServiceP.value = "";
            }
            if (txtMontant !== "") {
                txtMontant.value = "";
            }
            if (txtAnnee1 !== "") {
                txtAnnee1.value = "";
            }
            if (txtAnnee2 !== "") {
                txtAnnee2.value = "";
            }
            if (txtAnnee3 !== "") {
                txtAnnee3.value = "";
            }
            if (fileUpload !== "") {
                fileUpload.value = "";
            }
```

Comment: I do not understand... for example, Is `cboFamille` a string or a DOM reference? Is it related with the `cboF` param that function receives?

Comment: yes cboFamille and all the other parameters are DOM reference. All the variables are supposed to be declared where you can see "All variables...". I just did'nt have enough space to write all the code i have. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

if i got your questions correctly, follow this example it might help you

```
function func(...allParameters) {
  if (!allParameters.includes(""))
     allParameters = allParameters.map(_ => "")
}

func('ts', 'js');
```

Comment: Is it important to put 3 point before allParameters? And in (allParameters.map(_ => "")) , what does the underscore mean? i will try this when i'll have your answer :) Thank you Mohamed

Comment: 3 point mean to group all received parameters into one, for underscore in this case we do not need passed data from map for manipulation so we just put underscore